# Laravel Eloquent duplicate distinct row

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

[image]

Let's consider the image above. I would like to show duplicated entries as one entry and also I want to show the sum of the "`stock`" column. In this case it should be 5722.

Is it possible to do it using Eloquent? Or what are the best ways to do it?

Comment: Do you want it to show the one where the value is max?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your database / query is built but you could maybe use something like that:

```
Item::groupBy('item_name')
   ->selectRaw('*, sum(stock) as sum')
   ->get();
```

It will return a collection of Item with an additional “`sum`” field

Answer (score 0):

This will group the result with same medicine and supplier name and sum up the stock.

```
$result = Model_Name::groupBy('medicine_name','supplier_name')
                         ->selectRaw('*, sum(stock) as sum')
                         ->get();
```

Try this. Hope it might help you.

Comment: Did this Work ?

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030097/how-to-add-some-textfield-in-form-register-laravel-generator-infyom