# how to remove duplicates record from query results in sql using laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, laravel-5.3

i am getting same result in my sql query in laravel where id is different but class and subjects are same..so i if i try to get only class then that case i am getting same class name many time because their subjects are different some time some value is not same but class or subject are same. take example

```
ID    class    subject   total_student
 1     10       Math         40
 2     10       English      30
 3     10       Physic       40
 4     11       math         40
 5     11       Physics      10
 6     11       English      30
```

this is sample table view where i want to show only class then i am getting  10th class 3 times and 11 also 3times. so i want to remove this and want to get unique.

**my query is ::**

```
$classes = app_limit::with('classes')->where('institute_id', $institute-> id )->orderBy('id','asc')->get();
```

here app_limit table contain only those class id who are associated with a institute id  and having a relation with classes Table.

**my class model ::**

```
  public function app_limit()
            {
                return $this->hasMany('App\app_limit','classes_id');
            }
```

**App_limit model**

```
    function classes()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\classes');
}
```

so there is any solution for me. i tried distinct and groupBy.. but not work fir me .
can u tell me what is my solution.note that i want to get this result only from Institute id...
can it be possible to define closer function with **classes**

like ** with('classes'=>function($query){$query->distinct(name); });**

please also note that i am using sql server... so its solution should fallow sql server rules...

Comment: when i am executing this                                                                          $classes = app_limit::with('classes')->select('classes_id')->distinct()
                ->where('institute_id', $institute-> id )->orderBy('id','asc')->get(); then getting record as i want but problem is not getting  ID and other column from App_limit table...

Comment: how can i use groupby  in this query ::  users::select('id','name','age')->groupBy('name')->get();  please solve this query.. i want get id , name  , age  with only  grouping by name field.... .into sql server ...

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011498/laravel-eloquent-duplicate-distinct-row